# How to extract rows enumerated in array from matlab matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have some input data in a matrix. And i have array which classifies the data. It looks like this:

```
ds = [1 1; 2 -2; -1 -1.5; -2 -1; -2 1;];
class = [1 -1 -1 -1 1];
```

I need to extract only data rows where `class(class==x)`. How can i do it?

Comment: `ds(class==1,:)`

Comment: @Adiel you can write as an answer and i will accept

Comment: I don't think it should be considered as an answer... Glad that it helps you.

Comment: BTW, `class` is a keyword, you better not use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [Logical Indexing in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

In your case:

```
vUniqueClass = unique(class);    
for ii = 1:length(vUniqueClass)
    mA = mData(class == vUniqueClass(ii), :);
end
```

Comment: Note that you run mA up. `mA{ii}` would preserve the results.

Comment: And, why you iterate over each element of `class`?

Comment: I didn't fully understand the data structure of the OP. So you can think of it that at each iteration we extract a class which is defined by an element in `class`.

Comment: Elements in `class` are just classifiers, you don't need to do it for the same classifier (e.g., -1) more than one time. More than that, why you iterate over 1,2,3,... while class has values as 1 and -1? In your answer, you'll get some empty solutions, and you will not get the desired one for -1.

Comment: I think I understood from your comments the data structure and edited accordingly.

Comment: Ok, gets better. If I would think that it deserved to be an answer I would upvote also :) (see my commit). You can replace `mData` with `ds`- this is the data that referred by the classifiers. Also, consider that neat form: `for ii=unique(class), mA=ds(class==ii), end`